# Generating Dynamically OpenTok Session ID from iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using OpenTokSDK for iPhone (using it Natively)
I have made the code for calling but just there is one problem.:-
I have to statically Add the SessionID. But i want to generate the ID Dynamically.

How can I do this ?
Please help!

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Full disclosure: I am a developer for TokBox.

The only safe way to get session ID and token credentials to the device is by developing an application server that suits the specific needs of your app. We have a number of server-side SDKs available on GitHub ([link](https://github.com/opentok)) that will interface with the OpenTok server API to generate this data.

Note well the server-side SDK is enough to get your credentials generated, but not all devices will be on the same session, so things like user management and application workflows are all considerations that cannot be easily written to an open source library.

That said, we did try to make some of these examples more clear by writing code examples on our blog ([link](http://www.tokbox.com/blog/parse-has-opentok-ios-sdks-backend-so-you-dont-have-to/)). You can relieve much of the overhead of writing your own application server (no doubt a daunting task, especially the first time around) by leveraging one of the third party signaling services available, like [Parse](http://www.parse.com) and [Pusher](http://www.pusher.com), to name two.

Comment: quite useful, upvoted. My question is also along a beginners' line - could you also take a look as get a chance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267806/integrate-opentok-video-conferencing-into-ios-app

Answer (score 2):

Wobbals is correct, and In addition to what Wabbals has mentioned, generating sessions/tokens is very simple, the sample code required for each server language (PHP, NodeJS, C#, Ruby) is located in OpenTok's [Github page](https://github.com/opentok).

Furthermore, if you choose not to have server side code and use Parse to handle your back-end, there is a [wonderful writeup](http://www.tokbox.com/blog/parse-has-opentok-ios-sdks-backend-so-you-dont-have-to/) about how to use Parse's cloud code module for OpenTok to generate sessions and tokens.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I strongly felt that the tokbox tutorial was quite basic but had steeper learning curve. So I ended up wrote out my own app-cum-tutorial.

Though late, I felt compelled to post here:
[How To write your first iPhone Video Chat App using parse and opentok(tokbox)](http://www.iphonegamezone.net/how-to-write-your-first-iphone-video-chat-app-using-parse-and-opentok-tokbox/)